# In Python 2, can I pass a list to the percent-format operator?

Tags: python, string, list, string-formatting, python-2.x

I have a list of things I'd like to print using a format string.  In Python 3-style, using `"a string".format(arg,arg,arg)`, this is easy.  I can just replace with arguments with `*mylist`, like

```
mylist = [1,2,3]
"{} {} {}".format(*mylist)
```

I can't seem to make this work with the older percent-formatting.  I've tried stuff like `"%i %i %i" % mylist`, `%i %i %i" % (mylist)`, and `%i %i %i" % (*mylist)` but I just keep getting syntax errors or "not enough arguments".

Is this impossible in 2.x style?

ETA: I am changing the example above, I actually did mean *list*, not *tuple*.  I'm still learning and I'm not used to having two distinct array-like constructs.

Comment: For what it's worth, `(1, 2, 3)` is a tuple, not a list.

Comment: Are you aware that in Py2.7 you can also use .format, at least it works for me in 2.7.8

Comment: Ok, @falsetru made a mistake tagging the question with python-2.7... .format(*mylist) doesn't work on 2.6. For the percent format operator you need to convert the list to a tuple, what you already have in your exemple.

Comment: @Cld, No, It's not work in Python 2.6 not because of `format(*mylist)`, but because of the `{}`. (autonumbering is introduced in Python 2.7)

Comment: I mean the format(*mylist) exemple doesn't work, not format

Comment: @Cld, What do you mean?

Comment: Just to clarify (and notify those trying to help, in case the edit doesn't cause notification), I did in fact mean list, and I screwed up my example using tuple notation.

Comment: Also if it would help to clarify (by making it more backwards-compatible) I could change the autonumbering to use explicit numbers.  I was really trying to just come up with the simplest example of my syntax question that I could think of.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`str % tuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) should just work.

```
>>> mylist = (1, 2, 3)  # <---- tuple
>>> "%i %i %i" % mylist
'1 2 3'
```

BTW, `(1, 2, 3)` is a tuple literal, not a list literal.

```
>>> mylist = [1, 2, 3]  # <----- list
>>> "%i %i %i" % mylist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not list
```

If you want to make it work for list, convert the list into a tuple.

```
>>> "%i %i %i" % tuple(mylist)
'1 2 3'
```

Comment: The last bit was the answer I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print a list delimited by spaces, here is a more flexible solution that can support any number of elements

```
>>> l = [5,4,3,2,1]
>>> ' '.join(map(str,l))
'5 4 3 2 1'
```

This also works for tuples

```
>>> l = (5,4,3,2,1)
>>> ' '.join(map(str,l))
'5 4 3 2 1'
```

Comment: I was trying to use a very simple example.  I'm just trying to make sure I know how it works in the future, when I actually need custom formatting.